# Node.js support for Exporting excel and Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, export-to-excel

I am new to node.js.

I am currently in a pre-development phase of an application.

The application will be for tracking status of task of employee. The admin will have the right to export excel which will have data of employes for a given date range

Currently I am thinking WCF Service and SQL Server for the backend.

Few days back, someone told me about node.js and it's capabilities. And yes I was impressed

I wanted to know if I write a service with node.js, how will the service be hosted, also if I can write code for exporting data in excel, and lastly which database providers/adapters does node.js support?

Apologies if there is typo or this question need to be asked in any other community of stackExchange.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like that I need to have some good REST framework in node.js. For database option I guess I will have to go with  PostgreSQL or MySQL. For running the application as a service in windows, I will likely have to use NSSM (Non-Sucking Service Manager) for creating service entry in windows.

Comment: Guys if you have any other suggestion please let me know..

Comment: [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) is a good REST framework, Express is also good and mature.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great and simple plugin for Node to export Excel (xlsx).
https://npmjs.org/package/excel-export

As for the database, I'd recommend using MongoDB as it stores JSON.  It's a bit getting used to, but you'll like the concept of documents and it's query capabilities.  If you do get into it, here's a shortcut (took me a long time to wrap my head around this):

**MongoExplorer (Silverlight MongoDB Manager):**
http://mongoexplorer.com

**took me a long time to understand the connections of DBs, collections and then documents.  Mongo Explorer really helped.*

Comment: Thanks Jose. For excel I am using msexcel builder(https://npmjs.org/package/msexcel-builder) . I am also looking to MongoDB as of now and using mongoose in node.js to interact with MongoDB. I will surely use Mongoexplorer for viewing the collection and their documents.